# iMessage Extension: UITextField in UIViewController class brings up iMessage keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imessage-extension

I'm currently developing a small iMessage extension app, and it's composed of 3 classes:

One `MSMessagesAppViewController` class called `MessagesViewController`
and two `UIViewControllers` called `CompactViewController` and `ExpandedViewController`

The `MessagesViewController` is the parent view controller of the other two. It is responsible for transitioning between the two views when the user chooses the expanded or compact options in iMessage. I invoke the transition in my didTransitionTo() method like this:

```
let controller: UIViewController

controller = (presentationStyle == .compact) ? instantiateCompactVC() : instantiateExpandedVC()

addChildViewController(controller)
view.addSubview(controller.view)
controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

My problem lies in my ExpandedViewController class. In it, I have a text field that I intend to allow the user to type in. However, when the user taps on the text field, the iMessage keyboard pops up, instead of the default QWERTY keyboard.

I have yet to find a solution to this. I'm sure the type of keyboard that displays upon tapping the text field has something to do with the view controller or view hierarchy.

I want to allow the user to enter text normally with the default keyboard. How can I get around this?

Comment: Actually it always shows the iMessage keyboard. Does this avoid the user to type in the textField? In my app it works normally even if there is the iMessage keyboard

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti yes the iMessage keyboard is shown, but it doesn't allow the user to enter text into the textField. When the user enters text with the iMessage keyboard, the only option they have is to send that text into the iMessage conversaiton